# Crear aplicacion de java a .exe con Launch4j

Tags: java, launch4j

Desarrollé una aplicación en java en Netbeans. Lo que necesito es convertirla a `.exe` para usarla en un equipo que tiene Windows xp de 32 bits a este no tiene ni se le puede poner el JRE por cuestiones de seguridad.

Mi PC trabaja con Windows 10 a 64 bits, encontré un post que me explicaba como con el Launch4j podría resolver el problema del JRE pero al abrir la App en la computadora con Windows xp 32 bits me da un problema de compatibilidad.

¿Alguna idea de como poder resolver este problema?

Comment: forzosamente necesita ser .exe? si no, sólo instala Java y ya, no te compliques.

Comment: Hay una herramienta llamada JSmooth que te puede servir... http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch4j te permite descargar el en el pc destinatario el runtime java para ejecutar la aplicación.

Ya que en este caso no puedes instalarla, puedes descargar desde la página de Oracle un runtime java de 32 bits y meterlo junto con la aplicación y crear un script bat para ejecutarlo. Esto aumentará considerablemente el tamaño de la aplicación (Aplicaciones como JDownloader tienen embebido su propio runtime de java por ejemplo)

También puedes usar Avian http://readytalk.github.io/avian/ para integrar una pequeña maquina virtual jutno con la aplicación y tener el .exe

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me sirvio muy bien